# Remove line in xml based on project tag

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

Totally new to javascript and xml, I would like to delete a line from the projects of the following xml document:

```
<TEXTS>
 <Text Name="NewProject">NEW PROJECT</Text>
 <Text Name="Continue">CONTINUE</Text>
 <Text Name="RecentProjects">Recently used Projects:</Text>
</TEXTS>
 <LIST>
<Project ID="Visible" Name="Example1" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="adgjhh" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="dthdth" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="rssrhsrh" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="aaaef" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="aeeaaet" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="aeteta" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="aetetaetaetaetaeta" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="agdadg" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="dga" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="ghfj" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="hsrh" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="hteah" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="jrrjyrjy" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="jyrryjry" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="wtwet" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="yrryry" />
<Project ID="Visible" Name="yrtry" />
</LIST>
```

This is my try in JS:

```
 var fname="listOfProjects.xml";
        var xmldoc;

        var activeProjects;
        var inactiveProjects;

        var clickable;
        var greyed;

        var nodes;

        xmldoc= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
        xmldoc.load(fname);
        activeProjects = xmldoc.selectNodes("/STARTPAGE/LIST/Project[@ID='Visible']");
        clickable = "<LIST>";

        // Try and delete a random project for now
        var y = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Project")[5];
        y.parentNode.removeChild(y);
        //xmldoc.documentElement.removeChild(y);
```

Say I want to delete the project "Example1". First step would be to be able to just delete it based on index. My second goal is to be able to delete it based on text, meaning that I would like to search through all the projects, and delete "Example1" out of all of them.

Comment: Do you want to do that within old IE versions or why do you use `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")`? As for removing a node with the DOM, the line `y.parentNode.removeChild(y);` is the right approach. If you know you have `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")` then you can use XPath and `selectSingleNode('//Project[@name = "Example1"])` to select the element node and then delete as you already know.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, it is an older version of IE indeed. My current approach doesn't work however, even though I get no errors, meaning it doesn't get deleted. Is XPath something I can use immediately in my javascript?

Comment: The code should delete the node in the DOM (i.e. `xmldoc.xml` should no longer show the element), but of course it does not change the file you loaded from. As for XPath, `selectSingleNode/selectNodes` allow you to use that, although if you don't use `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0')` and only `xmldoc= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")`, then you need to make sure you call `xmldoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath')` before calling the `selectNodes/selectSingleNode` methods with XPath 1.0 expressions.

Comment: How can I make that change persist to the actual file, listOfProjects.xml?

Comment: Where do you load it from, over HTTP from a web server or from the local file system?

Comment: The local file system, it is in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a node, you can use XPath e.g.

```
xmldoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
var el = xmldoc.selectSingleNode('//Project[@name = "Example1"]');
```

to remove a selected node from the DOM use

```
if (el != null) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

to persist the changes made in the DOM to a file use the `save` method, i.e.

```
xmldoc.save("result.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you. However save fails, because "Permission denied".

Comment: @Iason, you have accepted the answer after posting your comment about the permission. Is that permission problem solved? Anyway, I have added the tag for Internet Explorer, perhaps that way someone can help with the permission problem if it still exists.

Comment: Yes, it sitll exists. Didn't know you can't write because of security concerns. I am now looking for a way to use javascript to fire an event in .NET webbrowser. If I can do this it will be more robust and I will be able to do anything I want.